# Fetch string matching a pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text like this -

```
EventTimestamp        H 9EventType 8document 2ID  2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302-DCUP  LogToAuditTrail  SourceAppCD 5DOCSV  SourceAppUID  2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302 6UserID  5a8ce656-1a31-456b-b3dd-5ec0859c9f3e1
```

I want to fetch the document-id which is present in the above string as

```
2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302
```

The Id has a specific pattern -

```
<8characters(alpha numeric)> - <4characters(alpha numeric)> - <4characters(alpha numeric)> - <4characters(alpha numeric)> - <12characters(alpha numeric)>
```

The above string has other similar ids, but I am interested in getting the pattern after the substring  `document 2ID`. Again this string is not fixed any kind of number, string or white space can come between `document` & `ID`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: From the looks of it, you're looking for an UUID so the characters aren't alpha-numeric but only the hex string subset (`[0-9a-f]`) thus a proper pattern would be: `[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12}`. Use case insensitive flag for case-insensitive UUIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.search`

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = "EventTimestamp        H 9EventType 8document 2ID  2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302-DCUP  LogToAuditTrail  SourceAppCD 5DOCSV  SourceAppUID  2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302 6UserID  5a8ce656-1a31-456b-b3dd-5ec0859c9f3e1"
m = re.search(r"document\s*\d+ID\s+([A-Za-z0-9\-]{36})", s)
if m:
    print(m.group())
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
document 2ID  2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302
2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302
```

Answer (score 0):

This Regex should fit your request.

```
((?:[A-z]|\d){8}-(?:(?:[A-z]|\d){4}-){3}(?:[A-z]|\d){12}-(?:[A-z]|\d){4})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex as well. This is just a code golf.

```
source = "EventTimestamp        H 9EventType 8document 2ID  2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302-DCUP  LogToAuditTrail  SourceAppCD 5DOCSV  SourceAppUID  2b837c02-40c9-4d33-b81b-d489a06fa302 6UserID  5a8ce656-1a31-456b-b3dd-5ec0859c9f3e1"
document_loc = value.find('document')
value = value[document_loc:]
id_loc = value.find('ID')
value = value[id_loc:].split()[1]
print(value)
```

In general, the string looks like that has predefined lengths of elements, if so, you should be able just to take a specific slice, or if tabs are used, just split on tab character, but that is just an assumption.